# getting a invalid syntaxerror for random.randint in python

Tags: python

I am new to python when I try this

```
randomNumber = random.randint(1,3)
```

I get a "invalid syntax" error. not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This works just fine for me, are you sure the error points on this line?

Comment: looks okay to me

Comment: Check the previous line of code to see if you're missing a closing parentheses.

Comment: what is the full code ?

Comment: Could there be an invisible character? This can sometimes happen when doing copy/paste from webpages. Most editors have a 'show invisible character' option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular (because your problem isn't reproducible with the given information) update your question with a reproducible example (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the random module?
If you did not put this on top of your code:

```
import random
```

Comment: I am running  "import random, sys" at the beginning of the code all lines up to this line seems to be working find and I get no error.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `import random` at the start of the file, hope it works this time!